# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'enable' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cornerstonejs

I am trying to setup a basic cornerstone react app. I have followed [this](https://docs.cornerstonejs.org/integration.html) example given by the cornerstone themselves. What I have tried to change is to convert the class based component to a functional based component reason being I am new to both react and cornerstone and functional components somehow make more sense to me then class based.

I have also setup a codesandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-archimedes-o770t) for you to take a look. I am getting this error of

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'enable' of undefined

but I am able to element in console.log in the very block.

Comment: You have to check if the elements in *cornerstoneTools* are not undefined. See the updated example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-snow-dfozb). The error *Cannot read property 'enable' of undefined* is generated by Typescript checks since the cornerstoneTools objects **can be** undefined.

Comment: actually the error was due to the difference in the version of cornerstoneTools. The code I copied was version 2 where what I had setup was version 4. Those functions are deprecated in version 4 and hence the error

Comment: Hi @umair.ashfr, can you share the functions used instead that are not deprecated in version 4 ?
Thanks for your help